# Can't install correct graphics driver - Intel Integrated HD Graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I've had Ubuntu installed for years on other pieces of hardware, and I've just recently purchased a Thinkpad x201 Tablet edition.

Thing is, I've been using the laptop for months now with no problems, the problem came up when i tried to install a game that requires OpenGL3, which should be no problem based on my hardware. Come to find out: Ubuntu has my graphics card listed as an Ironlake-era Mobile card. Upon researching, I found out that I actually have Intel Integrated HD Graphics on my i7 L640 cpu, which is a Sandy Bridge model, which fully supports OpenGL3. I've tried updating the drivers using the Intel Installer, but it hangs on committing a certain part. (I'd try to replicate this, but the whole process can be a pain, I've got to manually kill the process, restart into terminal mode and fix a a few things on the backend before I can get back into my system).

I'm currently upgrading to 15.10 with hopes that there might be some more stability, so that I can hopefully rerun the graphics driver installer without a hitch.

Just wondering if someone else knew how to deal with this problem. Overall, this is just a minor gripe, but it's something that I'd like to see taken care of.

Thanks for your help!

Robert Edwards

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is *Westmere* architecture and not *SandyBridge* and does not support OpenGL 3.0.

There are no additional drivers you need to install for this GPU with Ubuntu. The drivers included in Ubuntu provide full support.

Comment: I believe I spent an hour searching for information about the wrong CPU. Thank you for setting me straight.